# REST with hypermedia frameworks for .NET

Tags: .net, rest, asp.net-web-api, servicestack, hateoas

Looking to start a web API project and wondering which of the (two?) frameworks would allow me to go further in [Richardson Maturity Model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) with the least amount friction.

Perhaps a link to a HOWTO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply many of the practices mentioned by Richardson in almost all the existing HTTP oriented frameworks like ASP.NET Web API, NancyFX or ServiceStack to name a few. Here is an article I wrote describing how to build hypermedia services with ASP.NET Web API

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883957.aspx

Comment: Thanks, 
However, I understand that since what I'm returning is my DTO with the time and effort I can solve the rest of the problems with any underlying framework. I'm still curious which one prods me in the right direction and offers least friction getting there.

Comment: There is some friction with the current bits of ASP.NET Web API for unit testing the code that generates links or to have a better URL space control (You can use AttributeRouting in the meantime), but they are working on all these issues for the next version. I only worked with NancyFx in a project, and all I can say are good things. It's pretty simple and flexible. I don't have opinion about ServiceStack as I never work with it.

Comment: Thanks, I like a lot of what I'm seeing in NancyFx!

Comment: How did your experiences work out with Nancy and using hypermedia? Do you have any sample code?